# How to separate out the latitudes and longitudes and make a column for the mean values? - Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coordinates

I have a column in a Pandas data frame (there are other columns too in the data frame). The columns data is as:
[image]

Raw Data:

```
geo

{"type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[-114.539, 56.3398], [-115.849,
55.696], [-115.5279, 49.4193 ]]}  
{"type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[-117.0715, 53.18939], [-123.375, 52.9461]]}
```

Is there any way to separate out the latitudes and longitudes from the coordinates and then take the mean of latitudes and longitudes and then make separate columns for latitudes and longitudes corresponding to the same data, in the same data frame?

My ultimate goal is to calculate mean values for the latitudes and longitudes and make separate columns.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Kindly share the raw data

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `coordinates` value with `.str` accessor and explode it to rows and columns.

```py
df_ = df['geo'].str['coordinates'].explode()   # explode to rows
out = (df.join(pd.DataFrame(df_.to_list(),
                            columns=['latitudes', 'longitudes'],
                            index=df_.index)   # explode to columns
               .groupby(level=0).mean()))
```

```
print(df)

                                          geo
0           {'coordinates': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
1  {'coordinates': [[5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]}

print(df_)

0     [1, 2]
0     [3, 4]
1     [5, 6]
1     [7, 8]
1    [9, 10]
Name: geo, dtype: object

print(out)

                                          geo  latitudes  longitudes
0           {'coordinates': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}        2.0         3.0
1  {'coordinates': [[5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]}        7.0         8.0
```

---

If you don't care the performance, you can use `.apply(pd.Series)` to convert list to multiple columns

```py
out = df.join(df['geo'].str['coordinates'].explode()  # explode to rows
              .apply(pd.Series)                       # explode to columns
              .groupby(level=0).mean()
              .set_axis(['latitudes', 'longitudes'], axis=1))
```

---

Or you can use numpy to calculate the mean of axis 0

```py
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame((df['geo'].str['coordinates']
                            .apply(lambda lst: np.array(lst).mean(axis=0)).to_list()),
                           columns=['latitudes', 'longitudes']))
```

Comment: I am getting this error:`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (114, 1), indices imply (114, 2)` When I tried to change the `columns=['latitudes', 'longitudes']` to `columns=['latitudes longitudes']` then I get `NaN`

Comment: @Nephophile Which method do you use?

Comment: The first one. I tried the numpy one too but still getting the error.

Comment: @Nephophile Couldn't reproduce the error, could you check that your `df_` is like what I print, one column with a list of two elements? Also, what's the `df_.index`, is it a single index not multiple index?

Comment: My _df is like this:                                                                                                            ```0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
       ..
109   NaN
110   NaN
111   NaN
112   NaN
113   NaN
Name: .geo, Length: 114, dtype: float64```

Comment: and the df_.index is : ```Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
            ...
            104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113],
           dtype='int64', length=114)```

Comment: @Nephophile The index looks good to me, but the value is not. What's the value of `df['geo'].str['coordinates']`? Does it successfully extract the list of two elements?

Comment: It is giving me this output:                                                                               `0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
       ..
109   NaN
110   NaN
111   NaN
112   NaN
113   NaN
Name: .geo, Length: 114, dtype: float64`

Comment: @Nephophile What's the result of `type(df['geo'].iloc[0])`?

Comment: It's string: `str`

Comment: @Nephophile Use `df['geo'].apply(eval).str['coordinates'].explode()`

Comment: It's giving me this error now: `NameError: name 'false' is not defined`

Comment: @Nephophile Try `.apply(lambda x: eval(x, {'false': False}))`

Comment: df_ is giving me this output:                                                                            `0 [[[-114.539, 56.3398], [-11... 
0 [[[-114.539, 56.3167], [-11... 
1 [[[-115.849, 49.1173], [-11... 
1 [[[-115.5279, 48.3213], [-115... 
1 [[[-115.4215, 49.4193], [-11... 
... 
112 [[[-117.0715, 53.18939], [-11... 
113 [[[-117.1235, 54.12339], [-11... 
113 [[[-117.1657, 53.19919], [-1... 
113 [[[-123.375, 52.9461], [-11... 
113 [[[-123.123, 56.2558], [-11... 
Name: .geo, Length: 329, dtype: object
`

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. Now I am getting this error for **out**: `ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 821 columns`

Comment: @Nephophile Your `coordinates` data is not like what is in your example, I could do nothing to help.